# simple app memory usage

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I created an Android app with MvvmCross using 'Hot Tuna Starter Pack' from NuGet.
And did few changes:

In the generated FirstView layout I added a button

> ```
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     local:MvxBind="Click ShowNextScreenCommand"
>     android:textSize="40dp" />
> ```

In the FirstViewModel I added a command

```
 public IMvxCommand ShowNextScreenCommand { get { return new MvxCommand(() => this.ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>()); } }
```

I then created a second activity SecondView, for this I just copy-pasted FirstView.axml, FirstView.cs and FirstViewModel and renamed.
The only change is the command navigates back:

```
public IMvxCommand ShowNextScreenCommand { get { return new MvxCommand(() => this.Close(this)); } }
```

I run the app on a device and navigated back and forth between activities by clicking the buttons and observed the heap using DDMS.

The app started with 15MB allocated heap and after several navigations the allocated heap was 32MB after I clicked on 'Cause GC' in DDMS.

I spent more time switching between apps on the device or keeping device idle, but the allocated heap didn't decrease.

I would have expected the allocated memory to get freed.
I guess it does get eventually?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with looking at general Android memory management practices.  Remember that this is getting compiled down to the native bytes for an Android App so you should be able to use [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html) to debug any memory issues.

Comment: yes, I know the theory. I wasn't able to understand what's going on. I am testing on a real device